# Can't install wheels on docker for numpy

Tags: docker, numpy, pip, alpine-linux

this is my first time running Docker and I am having issues creating the image. This is the code inside my docker file

```
FROM alpine:latest

ENV PATH /usr/local/bin:$PATH

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip
RUN apk add py3-pip && pip3 install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /backend

COPY . /backend

RUN pip3 install wheel
RUN pip3 install numpy
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
```

Under `requirements.txt`, I have `numpy==1.23.1`.

The relevant error codes are

```
#12 8.606   Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): started
#12 22.30   Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'

#12 22.34 ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip3 install numpy]: exit code: 1
```

I tried searching for solutions but they mentioned that once you upgraded PIP, things should install fine. In this case, they still do not work well.

Do give any advice!

Comment: Are you on an ARM Mac by any chance? They sometimes have issues building these libraries

Comment: Try `pip3 install --extra-index-url https://alpine-wheels.github.io/index numpy` isntead. Does that work? If so, I can explain in an answer

Comment: pip3 install --extra-index-url https://alpine-wheels.github.io/index numpy actually worked! I was able to finish the image and run it. Thank you so much for helping! Would love to hear the explaination as well.

Comment: I've read that "normal" Linux wheels don't work on Alpine Docker images.  Does changing to the standard Docker Hub `python` image make a difference (start `FROM python:3.10`, don't separately install Python or Pip)?

Comment: I did try using FROM python:3.10.4 but it did not work as well with the same error. Using what the above commentor said worked and I was able to install numpy. I'm waiting for him to provide an answer before selecting it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pip3 install --extra-index-url https://alpine-wheels.github.io/index numpy isntead. Does that work? If so, I can explain in an answer

The above comment by FlyingTeller provided a solution for the problem.